# Mutual exclusion problem

Tags: concurrency, deadlock, pseudocode, mutual-exclusion, algol

The following solution to the mutual exclusion problem, discussed earlier, **published in 1966 by H. Hyman in the Communications of the ACM**. It was listed, in pseudo Algol, as follows.

```
  1 Boolean array b(0;1) integer k, i,
  2 comment process i, with i either 0 or 1, and k = 1-i;
  3 C0: b(i) := false;
  4 C1: if k != i then begin;
  5 C2: if not b(1-i) then go to C2;
  6     else k := i; go to C1 end;
  7     else critical section;
  8     b(i) := true;
  9     remainder of program;
 10     go to C0;
 11     end
```

why does it fails?, and is not a complete answer, I see the problem firstly because it only treats two processes, so it is not scalable...

Comment: How does the program continue after line 4?

Comment: There is a plenty of explanations in the Web why Hyman's algorithm is broken, including one at SO.